# Run two nginx instance using docker on same Machine

Tags: docker, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have two separate sites behind two separate nginx hosted on separate VPS using docker.

When I tried to have both nginx on the same VPS server as separate docker container, it doesn't work. The running container is overwritten with the newer one.

How can I host both nginx instance on same docker machine? Both redirecting to separate proxy_pass app but the nginx port are same, i.e. 80 & 443.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have 2 nginx container, both listening to the same port, you can use Docker in swarm mode. It has a built in load balancer which redirect the load to both of them. (note that in this case, both nginx instances must come from the same image)

Just use your current docker-compose file, but deploy it in the swarm mode.

Comment: Hi, I want to use different image!

Comment: Can you explain more? 2 different images listening on the same port? How it should decide which nginx each request should hit? I don't think that's possible, unless you add some sort of a gateway(maybe a third nginx) before these two.

Comment: Hmm.. that sounds like a good idea. But I get that it's not workable with current setup as both the sites are going to use same ports. Right?

Comment: If both of them are using the same gateway, no. Maybe you could make it work with something like subdomains or something like that, or merge the two nginx instances (their configurations). Or maybe there is a way, I'm not an expert in this

Comment: I'm not sure, as I said Im not an expert in this, but I'm pretty sure, you cant use 2 nginx instances on the same machine listening to the same port.

Comment: Do you want every requests go to both of them?

Comment: No. We want them to serve requests that arrives only on that particular domain.